# probability assigned to claims with information given

Tags: probability

I am taking a course of introduction to various distributions including both discrete and continuous.
In one of my assignment, there is an question I have no clues at all. It seems that this question has nothing to do with what I am learning.

In planning the operation of a new school, one school board member claims that four out of five newly hired teachers will stay with the school for more than a year, while another school board member claims that it would be correct to say three out of five. In the past, the two board members have been about equally reliable in their predictions, so that in the absence of any other information we would assign their judgement equal weight. If one or the other has to be right, what probability would we assign to their claims if it were found that 11 of 12 newly hired teachers stayed with the school for more than a year.

What I can come up with is that setting E(X)=4/5 from the first claim and E(Y)=3/5 from the second claim. Then find the Pr( E(X)= 4/5 | last year newly-hired teachers leaving school was 11/12) and Pr( E(X)= 3/5 | last year newly-hired teachers leaving school was 11/12) ? I wanna know if my direction to solving the problem is correct.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\hat{p}_1=\frac{4}{5}$ $\hat{p}_2=\frac{3}{5}$

We would like to find $$P(\hat{p}_1=\frac{4}{5} | p_0 =\frac{11}{12})$$ and

$$P(\hat{p}_2=\frac{3}{5} | p_0 =\frac{11}{12})$$

We have

$$\begin{align*}
P(\hat{p}_1=\frac{4}{5} | p_0 =\frac{11}{12})
&=\frac{P(\hat{p}_1=\frac{4}{5} \cap p_0 =\frac{11}{12})}{P(p_0 =\frac{11}{12})}\\\\
&=\frac{\frac{1}{2}{12\choose{11}}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{11}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{1}}{\frac{1}{2}\left({12\choose{11}}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{11}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{1}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left({12\choose{11}}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{11}\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^{1}\right)}\\\\
&\approx 0.9221092
\end{align*}$$

And the compliment of this would be $$P(\hat{p}_2=\frac{3}{5} | p_0 =\frac{11}{12})\approx 1-0.9221092\approx 0.07789081$$

Note: Needs to be checked!